An Interesting Puzzle on the Sequence of Positive Integers
There are $n$ positive integers on the blackboard. Each time two numbers are erased, and the absolute value of their difference is written on the blackboard. Finally, there is only one number left on the blackboard. What would be the maximum value of this number?

Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?  What exactly is your question? Are you looking for an algorithm for this problem, any algorithm? For the one with the best worst-case asymptotic running time?  What is the best algorithm you know of?  How do you plan to evaluate proposed answers?  What programming paradigms have you tried (greedy, dynamic programming, divide-and-conquer, etc.)?
